# RIP Dave Smith, inventor of the Prophet 5 synth

Tags: discussion

[Dave Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Smith_(engineer)?wprov=sfti1) (1950-2022) was a musician and engineer who founded [Sequential Circuits](https://www.sequential.com/) (a major synth manufacturer) and invented the Prophet 5 synthesizer.

The Prophet 5 was a significant milestone in synthesis because it was the first commercially available polyphonic synth, and it was the first with patch memory so users could save their sounds. The Prophet 5 was widely used in the 1980s, and can be heard on many hit songs, several movie soundtracks, and at least one hit Broadway musical, *Cats*.

Dave Smith was also a leader in the development of MIDI, as in he literally led the way. He conceived of a universal digital communication protocol for electronic instruments, and then worked with others to refine the idea to create the original MIDI standard.

On a personal note, I briefly met Dave Smith at Moogfest 2017 after attending a small Q&A with him. I found him to be very kind, patient, intelligent, and passionate about music, synthesis, and engineering. By all accounts, he was a wonderful person in addition to being a brilliant musical innovator.